# Given number which equals the sum of some of the 10 numbers. How to determine that given number contains one of 10 numbers?

Tags: algorithms

I have:

- ten numbers: +1, +2, +4, +8, +16, +32, +64, +128, +256, +512.
- flag == sum of some of this ten numbers.

How to determine that sum contains 2 or 32?

Comment: I don't understand what the question here is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's convert those numbers to binary:

```
1₁₀ → 0001₂
2₁₀ → 0010₂
4₁₀ → 0100₂
8₁₀ → 1000₂
```

Notice the pattern? Now take 7:

```
7₁₀ → 0111₂
```

By simply comparing the binary value, you easily see that there is 1, 2 and 4, but not 8. The same applies to any other number.

If you want to know how to determine if a number contains a flag in a specific programming language, read about bitwise operations. It is how zero or more flags can be combined to a single number, then evaluated to determine what flags are enabled.

Comment: May I ask you to write an example in any C-style language?

Comment: You can find the examples for C# at http://stackoverflow.com/a/417217/240613. As I said, for other languages, search for bitwise operations.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your numbers you could see that they are the form of 2^i where i=1...n; so only  one bit is affected by summing these numbers and there are no overflows.
Here is a table, to understand it better:

```
1 is 00000001
2 is 00000010
4 is 00000100
8 os 00001000
```

So you could simply use bit shift and 'and' operators to get the operands of the sum.
You calculate 1 & num to get the first (least significant) bit (I presume that your number is represented by one byte and called num). If it is 1, you have 1 in your sum. You shift your number by one to the right. Now you and with 1 again: if the result is 1 you have 2 in your sum, etc.